# Formatting floats in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, string, cocoa, formatting, floating-point

I need to format a float (catchy title, he?) to 2 decimal places, but only if those decimal places have values that aren't zero. Example:

I have a NSTextField named 'answer', after I do some math with a couple of floats, I want to assign my 'answerFloat' variable to the 'answer' NSTextField. So far I've got:

```
[answer setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", answerFloat]];
```

But that sets something like 45 to 45.00. I want whole numbers to be displayed without the zeroes, and any decimal numbers to be displayed with their respective decimal values.

Do I need to run some kind of check before giving it to stringWithFormat? Or does NSString offer a way to handle this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Have you tried the `%g` format specifier?

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g, %g", 45.0, 45.5]);
```

> 2010-01-12 19:54:38.651 foo[89884:10b]
>   45, 45.5

Comment: I actually thought I had tried %g. I just tried it like this:
    [answer setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.02g", answerFloat]];
and it worked like a charm. thanks!

Comment: the problem with this is that if the number is has large enough it will be put in exponential form. I don't think there is a way to get this asked for behaviour solely with format strings and without risking exponential form.

Answer (score 25):

The problem with %g is that it doesn't have a way to specify the rounding increment (at least, not that I can find).

You can use NSNumberFormatter like this to achieve your result with a number that has an undefined number of decimal places.

```
double none = 5;
double one = 5.1;
double two = 5.01;
double lots = 5.918286558251858392107584219;

NSNumber *numberNone = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:none];
NSNumber *numberOne = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:one];
NSNumber *numberTwo = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:two];
NSNumber *numberLots = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:lots];

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.roundingIncrement = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.01];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;

NSLog(@"%@",[formatter stringFromNumber:numberNone]);
NSLog(@"%@",[formatter stringFromNumber:numberOne]);
NSLog(@"%@",[formatter stringFromNumber:numberTwo]);
NSLog(@"%@",[formatter stringFromNumber:numberLots]);
```

Output:

```
2012-02-15 16:21:17.469 AwakeFromNib[53043:f803] 5
2012-02-15 16:21:17.470 AwakeFromNib[53043:f803] 5.1
2012-02-15 16:21:17.470 AwakeFromNib[53043:f803] 5.01
2012-02-15 16:21:17.471 AwakeFromNib[53043:f803] 5.92
```

Comment: Mark, brilliant answer and solved a problem I have been trying to fix for ages, thanks ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Look up NSNumberFormatter.

Comment: I just wanted to say I think your name rules. Awesome NSJoke.

Comment: It fits in with the job I used to do at Apple.

Comment: Please respond with appropriate help and possibly with an example. Even more so if your name is NSResponder! Thanks for you co-operation.

Answer (score 3):

For the greatest flexibility, you could consider implementing a [custom subclass of NSFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/CreatingACustomFormatter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000196-CJBFABHB).  There might be other salient tips in the [Data Formatting Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/DataFormatting.html).