# NSNumberFormatter, appending decimal to calculator from UI

Tags: objective-c, decimal, calculator, nsnumberformatter

Ok, so I am writing a calculator app now. So far, I'm not having much luck in regard to decimals (my most recent approach hasn't worked well).

```
-(void) DecimalAdded
{
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter  alloc] init]; 
    [formatter  setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [formatter  setAlwaysShowsDecimalSeparator:YES];
    [formatter setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:YES];
    [formatter setDecimalSeparator:@"."];

    //first convert the float value of CN into NSnumber

    NSNumber  *nextstepNumFromCNF= [NSNumber numberWithFloat:currentNumber];

    //now we have to convert that number into a string

    NSString *CNconverted = [formatter stringFromNumber:nextstepNumFromCNF];




    NSNumber *CNdecmAddedAndReadyForPars = [formatter numberFromString:CNconverted];

    currentNumber = currentNumber*10 + [CNdecmAddedAndReadyForPars floatValue];

    CalculatorScreen = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"%@", CNconverted];
```

I can append the string to the Calculator screen I can say the number is 1, I see "1." as I'm typing. However this is usually converted to 1 during th float conversion (which is correct).

What is this best way to accomplish this?

Comment: a style comment for you:  method (function) names and variable names should always start with a lower case letter in Objective C.  Class names are what start with capital letters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054218/formatting-floats-in-objective-c